# Excel countifs with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I'm trying to count all the people in an excel file that scored less than 75 on exam 1 but scored over 900 on either exam 2 OR 3. I tried using `countifs` but if both exam 2 and exam 3 are over 900, it counts them twice. Any suggestions? Please help!

I've tried `sumproduct` as well but I can't figure out how to include an `OR` condition that's based on 2 separate columns

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C, "<75",$E:$E,">900",$F:$F,">900")
```

I would expect to keep a count of all the students that meet this criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an array formula (entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

```
=SUM( (C3:C5<75)*
      (1*(E3:E5>900)+1*(F3:F5>900)>0) )
```

Comment: Or `SUMPRODUCT` and then you no longer need Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It is also faster to use `--` instead of `1*` to convert from Bool to Int:  `=SUMPRODUCT(--(C3:C5<75) * SIGN(--(E3:E5>900) + (F3:F5>900)))`

Comment: This one is probably easier to understand. A couple questions (and pardon my excel ignorance), what are the "--" for and why is SIGN used? Is it because SIGN would return either a 1 or 0 for this data? THANK YOU

Comment: @bsquared82 The `--` is because `(F3>0)` will return `True` or `False`.  To convert it into `1` or `0`, we can either Add 0 (`0+(F3>0)`), multiply by 1 (`1*(F3>0)`) or double-negate it from `True`/`False` to `-1`/`0` and then `-(-1)`/`0` a.k.a. `1`/`0`.  Lots and lots of testing has shown that the most efficient way to do this is `--`, which uses the least CPU and Memory.  `SIGN` is used because it will turn `--(A3>0)+(B3>0)` from `0`/`1`/`2` to `0`/`1`/`1` which eliminates the double-counting (i.e. `--( (--(A3>0)+(B3>0)) >0)`)

Answer (score 1):

```
=countifs("*Exam 1 cell*","<75","*Exam 2 cell*",">900","*Exam 3 cell*","<900")

+countifs("*Exam 1 cell*","<75","*Exam 3 cell*",">900","*Exam 2 cell*","<900")

+countifs("*Exam 1 cell*","<75","*Exam 2 cell*",">900","*Exam 3 cell*",">900")
```

I was just very specific in my conditions for what I wanted the formula to count:

1) exam 1 < 75 , exam 2 > 900 , exam 3 < 900

2) exam 1 < 75 , exam 3 > 900 , exam 2 < 900

3) exam 1 < 75 , exam 2 > 900 , exam 3 > 900

Answer (score 0):

This formula works for what you need:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($D:$D,"<75"),IF(SUM(COUNTIF($E:$E,">900"),COUNTIF($F:$F,">900"))>1,1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This one is the easiest to understand, however the result here is a 2. For the conditions I'm describing, I would want this formula to produce a 1 since it meets the criteria. I would like either a 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract when both are over 900 from the sum of when each is over 900:

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C, "<75",$E:$E,">900",$F:$F) + COUNTIFS($C:$C, "<75",$F:$F,">900") - COUNTIFS($C:$C, "<75",$E:$E,">900",$F:$F,">900")
```

Why does this work?

```
Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 ::: CountIfs1 + CountIfs2 - CountIfs3 === Result
 100  |   75  |   75   :       0    +      0    -      0     =     0
  70  |   75  |   75   :       0    +      0    -      0     =     0
  70  |  901  |   75   :       1    +      0    -      0     =     1
  70  |   75  |  901   :       0    +      1    -      0     =     1
  70  |  901  |  901   :       1    +      1    -      1     =     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUMPRODUCT`

Formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((C:C<75)*(E:E>900)*(F:F>900))`

Results:

[image]